# Modify an eps image using LaTeX

Tags: graphics, eps

Can I use LaTeX to remove the **stop** and **pause** buttons from an `.eps` image?
[image]

Comment: I would say perhaps, but I think that with many tools specifically made for the job, why use LaTeX?

Comment: If the image comes from a screenshot, then a bitmap format like PNG would be easier to correct.

Comment: You can't remove them. You could probably hide them. (Certainly with PNG or something like that - not sure with EPS.)

Comment: To expand on the comment by @cfr : you can hide parts of an `eps` image in the same way as with other filetypes, e.g., `\includegraphics[trim={0cm 5mm 0cm 0cm},clip]{mygraph.eps}` (trim order is left, bottom, right, top).

Comment: how can I change the width of the eps image and hide parts in the same time?

Comment: if the function of curve on the image is know or known values of their point, it seems to be more simple redraw image in for example `pgfplots` ...

Comment: Unrelated to the specified question, but this image also appears to have been squashed, probably by specifying both a width and a height. If this figure is intended to show software functionality, I'd leave the screenshot as is and specifying either a width or a height. If it's intended to show data, I'd redraw it with pgfplots as Zarko suggested.